# Debian: daemon program quits immediately when run as jenkins user

Tags: daemon, jenkins

I'm trying to run an IRC bot as a daemon using `daemon` (also tried with the `daemonize` utility),

I use the following command to run it,

```
daemon --name=HsIRCb --chdir=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HsIRCb/workspace --command=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HsIRCb/workspace/dist/build/HsIRCb/HsIRCb --pidfile=/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/HsIRCb/workspace/HsIRCb.pid
```

When I run the command as root, it works and the bot connects and stays there like it's supposed to, but when I ask jenkins to run it, it connects and quits immediately.

I've also tried to log in as the jenkins user, and still no dice (doesn't throw any errors).

It's worth noting that on normal users it works, it's only a problem with the user created by jenkins.

So, I'm wondering, is there some permissions that the jenkins user doesn't have, or should it be in some group or something?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `screen` instead of `daemon` / `daemonize`? It is generally more featureful and tolerant of things like manipulating the shell, etc.

Try

`screen -mdS HsIRCb /path/to/command`

There are ways for you to do things like changing directory, logging in as a different user, etc. but this is the basic idea.